# Does Kafka support secure communication?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have been reading a lot of Apache Kafka documentation, but am unable to find if Kafka supports secured communication between Producers-Brokers, Brokers-Consumers, and especially for inter-data center communication for broker replication.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update**: As of 0.9.0.0 the SSL implementation is added to Kafka. The SSL configuration should be added explicitly on the broker side.

It is even possible to enable SSL for inter-broker communication by adding following property to the broker's property file.

`security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL`

Regarding the producer and consumers the SSL is only supported for the new API.

For details regarding generation of key, certificate and configuration please check [deploying SSL for Kafka](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Deploying+SSL+for+Kafka)

**Previous Releases**

Before 0.9.0.0
Kafka **`does not`** support SSL/authentication and as far as my understanding goes they do not have it in their near team road map. One way could be to use encryption at your end and send the encrypted data through producers. 
However they have [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Security) discussion regarding implementing security in future. 
Similar discussion can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kafka-dev/ZmJrB_plu1I)

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @ppearcy for his findings

> Likely things changed since this was posted, but currently security is on the roadmap: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Security

Comment: Things have changed. Kafka 0.9.0.0 release adds SSL support to Kafka. See [Deploying SSL for Kafka](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Deploying+SSL+for+Kafka)

Answer (score -2):

There have been [patches](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1477) to support client authentication and secure in transit message delivery but note this has not made it to any production release yet. 
There are interesting discussions and future work that includes client authentication, authorization as well as encryption of data at rest https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@kafka.apache.org/msg11664.html